# How to replace Raid1 hard drives with large ones using Storcli tool

Tags: vmware-esxi, raid1, lsi, storcli

I have raid1 with 2 physical drives (SATA 3.637 TB).
I want to extend it's size with large ones without losing data.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DG Arr Row EID:Slot DID Type  State BT       Size PDC  PI SED DS3  FSpace TR
 0 -   -   -        -   RAID1 Optl  N    3.637 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 0 0   -   -        -   RAID1 Optl  N    3.637 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 0 0   0   252:3    4   DRIVE Onln  N    3.637 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   1   252:2    5   DRIVE Onln  N    3.637 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 1 -   -   -        -   RAID1 Optl  N  446.625 GB enbl N  N   none N      N  
 1 0   -   -        -   RAID1 Optl  N  446.625 GB enbl N  N   none N      N  
 1 0   0   252:1    6   DRIVE Onln  N  446.625 GB enbl N  N   none -      N  
 1 0   1   252:0    7   DRIVE Onln  N  446.625 GB enbl N  N   none -      N  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG       Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model               Sp Type
252:0     7 Onln   1 446.625 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B INTEL SSDSC2KB480G8 U  -    
252:1     6 Onln   1 446.625 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B INTEL SSDSC2KB480G8 U  -    
252:2     5 Onln   0   3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST4000NM0035-1V4107 U  -    
252:3     4 Onln   0   3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST4000NM0035-1V4107 U  -    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As I understood the steps must be:

1. Mark one drive as failed

   ```
   storcli /с0/e252/s2 set offline

   storcli /с0/e252/s2 set missing


   storcli /с0/e252/s2 set spindown
   ```

   Note: I've disabled automatic rebuild in this step. It started after set missing command.
2. Make LED of this disk blink:

   ```
   storcli /с0/e252/s2 start locate

   storcli /с0/e252/s2 stop locate
   ```
3. Replace with large one
4. Start rebuild process and wait

   if not started automaticaly:

   ```
   storcli /с0/e252/s2 insert dg=0 array=0 row=1

   storcli /с0/e252/s2 start rebuild
   ```
5. WAIT...
6. Repeat: Mark other drive as failed, replace them, etc.
7. Extend array whith new size.

   ```
   storcli /c0/v0 expand size=<amout of MB to add> expandarray
   ```

Thank you for help.

I am using esxi6.7 with Storcli installed and working.

I've edited question to update collected info and added some commands.

Last UPDATE: I've managed succesfully update my disks using above comands. It takes 3 days including rebuild.

During reboot I've lost datastore in ESXI WEB (ESXI 6.7 bug). After ESXI 6.7 latest update datastore showed again and i finally managed to extend datastore with web-interface.

Hope it will helpfull for someone.

Comment: Can't you just backup and restore?

Comment: One of my goal is not stopping server. And it would be nice not to reboot it.

Comment: Surely you have a second server available to allow for outages, patching etc?

Comment: Yes, but all this backup/restore operation is time consuming. Stoping server is my last option.

Comment: Sorry what I'm saying is that 99% of production systems are designed so that there's not a single server that could impact performance, using clustering or something similar. It's very rare in professional environments to find a single server whose outage would impact the service.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The solution is in the question.

I'm using this command to see the progress:

```
while true ; do clear ; date ; storcli /c0/e252/s6 show rebuild ; sleep 5 ; done
```

where `/e252/s6` is the enclosure and slot which you just replaced with a bigger disk.

Comment: You should be able to use `watch -n5 storcli /c0/e252/s6 show rebuild` instead of the above loop to do basically the same thing